# Lazy Initialization Sanity Check: Variable might not have been initialized

Tags: java, android, lazy-evaluation, lazy-initialization, short-circuiting

I'm combining existing import and export functions in order to reduce the number of times the user gets told the connection was refused in the event that the connection does get refused. The library I'm calling has separate import and export functions, as well as a combined import/export function. The export function requires the list of files to be exported, while the combined function figures out the list by itself (and internally calls the export function with this list). Since either import or export can be turned off by the user, I want to only get the list of files if necessary.

I have come up with this code:

```
List<File> files;
if (mExport)
    files = ListFiles();

if (mExport && mImport && files.size() > 0) // Error is on files
    DoExportAndImport();
else if (mImport)
    DoImport();
else if (mExport && files.size() > 0) // No error here
    DoExport(files);
```

The second `if` statement gets marked with the error `Variable 'files' might not have been initialized` (but not the last one).

Help me with my reasoning here: if `mExport` is true, then `files` gets initialized; but if `mExport` is false, then the second `if` statement gets short-circuited and never reaches `files`, so it doesn't matter that `files` hasn't been initialized, because it isn't being used.

Am I overlooking something here, or is this just too complex a situation for the compiler to work out? If the latter, is there any way to tell the compiler to knock it off, I've got it handled?

For the record, initializing `files = new ArrayList<>()` in the declaration does silence the compiler, as does `files = null`, though that obviously leads to other errors; but it just feels like such a waste to initialize a value that I know is never going to be used or referred to in any way.

Comment: `files = Collections.emptyList()` might be a better "dummy" initializer, as this does no allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is sound in that `files` will always be initialized with each case in which `files` is referenced.  However, as you've suspected, the compiler doesn't go that far.  Its static analysis does not take into account the values of variables to determine whether a certain condition will always be true or false.

In this case, the compiler doesn't take into account that `files` is initialized if `mExport` is `true`.  It only sees the possibility that `files` is not initialized from the top `if` statement, and that it is reference below that statement.

You can help by rearranging your logic so that it's only referenced from within the `if` statement block.

```
List<File> files;
if (mExport) {
    files = ListFiles();
    if (mImport && files.size() > 0) {
        DoExportAndImport();
    } else if (files.size() > 0) {
        DoExport(files);
    }
} else if (mImport) {
    DoImport();
}
```

Comment: This almost gets me there, but it doesn't call DoImport() if there aren't any files. It will require an extra if case to handle that.

Comment: But it did give me the inspiration to set mExport to the result of files.size() > 0 in the first if statement, which I think will work.

Comment: Nope, it just moves the complaint down to my `DoExport(files)` call.

Answer (score 0):

Static analyzer is not ultimate AI. Sometimes it may give false positives. You should be able to mute complaints on this particular line, however I would suggest to rather rework the logic of the whole code block to make it simpler.

Also `files = null` is redundant as `files` is `null` unless initialized otherwise. It is just fooling analyser.